# How do I display a form in Visual Studio Community 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

What is the Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 command equivalent for the VS 2013 command

```
Form1.Show();
```

I am trying to learn Visual Studios Community 2015.  I watched this beginner's video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K46809Gw3Sc

(which I didn't notice until I was trying to go through the steps in VS 2015, that the video was for VS 2013) showing how to create two forms.  The video clearly demonstrates how to move back and forth between the two forms.  Unfortunately, the `Form1.Show()`, `Form2.Show()`, and `Form2.Label2.Text = (TextBox1.Text)` commands don't work in 2015.

It's such a shame they didn't work!  This video would have been so useful!

I did look extensively here on Stack Overflow and I googled my questions, trying to see if anyone else asked this question, but I did not get any hits on this exact topic.  Having said that, I am so new to Visual Studios that I am not sure I used the "right words" to search.  "Form" and "Visual Studios" and "Show" are all pretty vague and get huge lists of search results.

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of project did you create? If it's a "Windows Forms" application, there is no difference between Vs2015 and Vs2013

Comment: Jessehouwing, thank you for answering. Yes, it is a Windows Forms application. But I don't know VS2013, so I don't know what to do with your answer. Also, I see now that the example demo is Visual Basic, and I need C++ code.

Comment: C++ is a whole different story. As far as I know Windows Forms support for C++ was dropped in Visual studio 2012. You can develop your forms using C# or VB.NET and from there call into your Managed C++ or even unmanaged C+ code. There is no advantage to building your forms in C++, other than the familiarity with the language, if you have that. If you are starting with a new solution, then I highly advise you to look into Windows Presentation Foundation instead of native C++ or WInForms.

Comment: Jessehouwing, thank you again for answering. You are correct. I misspoke. I did not need C++ code; I needed C#. When I wrote that I didn't know there was a difference. In any event, 'Form1.Show();' does indeed make the form appear. How do I make a checkmark saying that your first comment on Sept. 30 was correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you want simply use WinForms, then selecting a C# or VB.NET project is so much easier than doing it in C++, where you're more likely to use MFC.

You can host the WinForms front-end inside a C++ managed and even unmanaged application by hosting the CLR inside your application.